# How to get content of Django ImageField before it is saved?

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-models

I'm trying to resize an image while saving an instance of my model.

```
class Picture(models.Model):
  image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to="pictures")
  thumb_file = models.ImageField(upload_to="pictures", editable=False)
  def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    image_object = Image.open(self.image_file.path)
    #[...] nothing yet
    super(Picture, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

The problem is that self.image_file.path does not exist before the model is being saved. It returns a correct path, but the image is not there yet. Since there is no image, I can't open it in PIL for resize.

I want to store the thumbnail in thumb_file (another ImageField), so I need do the processing before saving the model.

Is there a good way to open the file (maybe get the tmp image object in memory) or do I have to save the whole model first, resize and then save again ?

Answer (score 1):

I used [this snippet](https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/wiki/CustomUploadAndFilters/imaging.py):

```
import Image

def fit(file_path, max_width=None, max_height=None, save_as=None):
    # Open file
    img = Image.open(file_path)

    # Store original image width and height
    w, h = img.size

    # Replace width and height by the maximum values
    w = int(max_width or w)
    h = int(max_height or h)

    # Proportinally resize
    img.thumbnail((w, h), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # Save in (optional) 'save_as' or in the original path
    img.save(save_as or file_path)

    return True
```

And in models:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Picture, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.image:
        fit(self.image_file.path, settings.MAX_WIDTH, settings.MAX_HEIGHT)
```

Comment: that works, but i want to store the thumb in another imagefield.. that's why i have to do the resize before saving the model.

Comment: no problem, create new image in fit function with prefix in name. Ex "t_".  And in model add function wich return path to your thumb.

Comment: but in your example the fit function is called after the model was saved. so adding the thumb to an extra image-field would require a second save. and that's what i'm trying to avoid.. and if i just called the save function at the end, i couldn't use the imagefile, because it's not saved yet :(

Comment: No, i do not mean create new ImageField. I mean create new image file for thumb (on yor hdd). 
And in model: def thumb: return "%st_%s" % (path_to_image, image_name)

Comment: that doesn't sound too bad. although i'd prefer to store it in a field.. thanks for the tip!

Comment: Add ImageField(blank=True, null=True) into model. In save: do resize and fill thumb ImageField data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can open the file directly and pass the resulting file handle to `Image.open`:

```
image_object = Image.open(self.image_file.open())
```

Sorry, I can't test that now.

Comment: no it doesn't work either .. 
>'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 0):

On your model `save` method the field value will be a valid `FileField` or `ImageFileField` in the case of an `ImageField`. This django class implements the object file interface (i.e `read`, `write`) and it works even before the file is saved with your model, so you can use it as the parameter to `PIL.Image.open`:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to="pictures")
    thumb_file = models.ImageField(upload_to="pictures", editable=False)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        img = Image.open(self.image_file)
        # work with img, is an Image object
        super(Picture, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

This works on django `>= 1.5`.