# Django: FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory

Tags: django, django-models

I'd just like to check if my Django model works or not(By trying create a new model instance on admin page). However I get **`FileNotFoundError at /admin/appname/modelname/add/`** [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '**`/home/user/PycharmProjects/myproject/media/file_I_wanna_upload.file`**' (It's an absolute path where the uploaded file should be situated after saving my new model instance).

In my **`settings.py`**:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In my project's **`urls.py`**:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
                  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                  ...
              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                         document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
                         )
```

And finally my **`models.py`**

```
from PIL import Image as I

class Image(models.Model):
    galery = models.ForeignKey(Galery, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        img = I.open(self.image.path)
        img.resize(size=(300, 300))
        img.save(self.image.path)
        return super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Everything seems be working good. However it doesn't.

Here is another `model` that I have no problems with:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, related_name='userprofile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default="default.png", upload_to='avatars', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10 ** 4, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.username)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

What am I doing wrong? Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the image.path won't exist until you've saved the instance. You could re-write your model as follows:

```
    class Image(models.Model):
        galery = models.ForeignKey(Galery, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
    
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            img = I.open(self.image.path)
            img.resize(size=(300, 300))
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

This is very similar to the next question: [How to get content of Django ImageField before it is saved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775424/how-to-get-content-of-django-imagefield-before-it-is-saved)